# Django templates coding style

Tags: django, coding-style, django-templates

Is there coding style which determines how to write code in templates?
this way:

```
<tbody>
    {% for row in body_rows %}
    <tr>
        {% for cell in row %}
        <td>{{ cell.val }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

this:

```
<tbody>
{% for row in body_rows %}
    <tr>
    {% for cell in row %}
        <td>{{ cell.val }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

or this:

```
<tbody>
    {% for row in body_rows %}
        <tr>
            {% for cell in row %}
                <td>{{ cell.val }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rule for code in Django templates is simple and consistent just like with any other coding language. Make things clear, and do so consistently.

Unlike Python, template code really does not need to be indented, but I always indent, since I'm quite used to Python's indentation. But that is simply a matter of preference.

However, I along with many other people who use Django prefer the 3rd method of doing things that you just showed. It is the most common type that I've seen although the second way is also fairly common.

Also keep logic inside templates to a minimum, and let other things like your views and filters take care of the real heavy-lifting, when it comes to logic.

Other than that, you're good to go.

Also remember that in django, you can have different templating engines, for example the way you are doing it is simply using Django's default templating engine. You can also choose to configure django to use other templating engines like Mako or Jinja  (all of Python's templating engines seem to be named after something Japanese).

And the communities behind these other templating languages have their own modus operandi when it comes to their syntax. But in all cases, the 3rd one is the clearest of them all (to me, and a lot of people from all these templating engines seem to use them).

So, short answer: 3rd one. Long answer: you chose.

Comment: tldr: "3rd one. Long answer: you chose."

Answer (score 1):

There is a Django style guide but it is very limited: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#template-style

Personally I usually do it like this with the simple reason that my default indenting rules do this for me:

```
<tbody>
    {% for row in body_rows %}
    <tr>
        {% for cell in row %}
        <td>{ cell.val }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```